# mysql transaction - update field with condition matching the same field

Tags: mysql

I need to update the ladder level in mysql table join_ladder.
The query is like below:

```
START TRANSACTION;
UPDATE join_ladder SET ladder_level=1 WHERE user_id=129;
UPDATE join_ladder SET ladder_level= ladder_level+1 WHERE ladder_level >= 1 AND ladder_level <= 3 AND playing_level=3 and user_id!=129;
commit;
```

the table looks like this before execution:

```
id  user_id location    playing_level   ladder_level    
1   126        1             1               1  
2   129        1             3               3  
3   130        1             3               2  
5   131        1             2               1  
6   136        1             3               1
```

I expect the result like this after execution of the query:

```
id  user_id location    playing_level   ladder_level    
1   126        1             1               1  
2   129        1             3               1  
3   130        1             3               3  
5   131        1             2               1  
6   136        1             3               2
```

but I am getting it like this:

```
id  user_id location    playing_level   ladder_level    
1   126        1             1               1  
2   129        1             3               1  
3   130        1             3               4  
5   131        1             2               1  
6   136        1             3               4
```

looked at the code from all angles, but looks like I am missing something obvious.

Comment: Seems to be working https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=85d34dd0dde885aefefbe5ca7fc92512

Comment: strange. I am running the same query in phpmyadmin, I am getting the wrong result. will recheck. Thanks.